# ClearCase UCM: Is it possible to delete a project?

Tags: clearcase, clearcase-ucm

Can a ClearCase administrator or a project manager delete a project including all its streams, views, baselines, activities etc.? How?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

- You cannot easily delete a project, unless all its streams are deleted
- You cannot easily delete a stream if there are versions created on a branch made from that streams (or if there are any views or any activities attached to that stream).
- You cannot easily activities unless you have deleted first every versions in it (or move them to another activity)
- and so on...

Bottom line, ask for the owner of the project to obsolete it (and its streams):

```
cleartool lock -obs stream:astream@\myPVob
cleartool lock -obs project:myProject@\myPVob
```

It is a much more lightweight operation with less side-effects and:

- the project and its streams will be invisible
- nobody will be able to checkout/checkin any file on those streams (ie on the branches created from those streams)