# Delete branch in clearcase in Eclipse using GUI operation

Tags: eclipse, branch, clearcase

There is a good answer here on [how to create a ClearCase branch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2110023/how-to-create-a-branch-in-clearcase-with-gui-operation-only) using GUI operation only. I have created such a branch and worked in it and now I wish to delete since it has been merged. I have not dared trying to simply delete the BranchType in ClearTeam Explorer since I am afraid it might corrupt something.

How to delete a branch in ClearCase and ClearTeam Explorer for Eclipse using GUI operation only?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally, I wouldn't recommend to delete anything, especially with ClearCase UCM.

The usual solution is to make the stream (UCM) or the brtype (base ClearCase) obsolete.

```
cleartool lock -obs stream:xxx@\apvob
or
cleartool lock -obs brtype:xxx@\avob
```

That way, the branch becomes invisible.

Comment: Thanks. I'm afraid I don't have access to the cleartool commands at my workstation. To execute them I have to log onto one of our dev servers :/. We are only using web-views, maybe it can affect the situation?

Comment: Then right click on the stream, you should have a lock option

Comment: @span note: web-views means CCRC (ClearCase Remote Client) either 7.1.x or 8.0.x. You should have access to `rcleartool` (http://stackoverflow.com/a/21577362/6309).

Comment: Thank you @VonC, I will look into it. The environment we are working in is insanely locked down so I doubt I can access `rcleartool` although I hope so. I'll keep the question unanswered to see if someone can come up with a way to do this in GUI for now.

Comment: @span do you mean my previous comment about right-clicking on the stream (in the GUI) didn't show the "lock" option?

Comment: So I have had Another look and I can't find the lock options. I have done some testing using "Remove Branch Type" in the ClearTeam Explorer and that seems to have done the job although you recommended against this. If you can, please elaborate on why it is a bad idea?

Comment: @span see for example http://stackoverflow.com/a/7529745/6309. The risk is to have dangling objects.